# Running a Python script via systemd

Tags: python, service, systemd

I am pretty new to writing `systemd` service scripts. I was following this [useful page](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/) to write my own. It is failing as below.

The `prodKPI.service` contents in `/etc/systemd/system/` in a `Centos 7` machine are as

```
[Unit]
Description=prodKPI: Aggregation logic to compute device availability

[Service]
Type=simple
PermissionsStartOnly=true
User=deployuser
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python /tmp/app1/folder1/file1.py; /usr/bin/python /tmp/folder2/file2.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The steps I followed after creating the file are

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable prodKPI.service
```

did a `reboot` and

```
# systemctl status prodKPI.service
● prodKPI.service - prodKPI: Aggregation logic to compute device availability
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/prodKPI.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Fri 2017-07-21 19:20:41 UTC; 15min ago
  Process: 1190 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /tmp/app1/folder1/file1.py; /usr/bin/python /tmp/folder2/file2.py (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 1190 (code=exited, status=2)

Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: prodKPI.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: Unit prodKPI.service entered failed state.
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: prodKPI.service failed.
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: prodKPI.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for prodKPI.service
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start prodKPI.service: Aggregation logic to compute device availability.
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: Unit prodKPI.service entered failed state.
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: prodKPI.service failed.
```

which did not help much, from

```
journalctl -xe

-- Unit prodKPI.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: Starting prodKPI.service: Aggregation logic to compute device availability...
-- Subject: Unit prodKPI.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit prodKPI.service has begun starting up.
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 python[1190]: /usr/bin/python: can't open file '/tmp/app1/folder1/file1.py;': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: prodKPI.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: Unit prodKPI.service entered failed state.
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: prodKPI.service failed.
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 systemd[1]: prodKPI.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1: start request repeated too quickly for prodKPI.service
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1: Failed to start prodKPI.service: Aggregation logic to compute device availability.
```

The error line below indicates some kind of permission issues? Should the service unit be run with a different user (or) access levels? I changed the both the python files to be executable also

```
Jul 21 19:20:41 device-1 python[1190]: /usr/bin/python: can't open file '/tmp/app1/folder1/file1.py;': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When *Type* is not *oneshot* you can only provide one *command*.

Also you are using *bash* syntax in your command. You have to wrap it in an intermediate Shell Process if you wan't to use *bash* syntax. I.e.:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "python /tmp/app1/folder1/file1.py; /usr/bin/python /tmp/folder2/file2.py"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am able to make the service running now. I do have a couple of clarifications. 1) did you mean `/usr/bin/python` for the first python script? 2) With this `bash -c` option, I can see only the first script being running in the background from `ps -ef | grep [p]ython` and not able to see the second script running? Any idea how to make it run too? Would gleefully accept the answer then

Comment: Eventually found the fix to the problem!